# Dynamically setting background image on Grid cell with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

The program I am creating is a meme generator. I have a div container set up with display:grid with a few tags inside of that which act as the top and bottom text for the meme. I'm trying to dynamically set the background image for the grid cell using plain vanilla JS. When I attach the link inside the CSS file it works perfectly, but using JS the background-image is never set when i check inside the browser. I put a big arrow so you can see where I am attempting to set the image

```js
const imageLink = document.querySelector('#imageLink');
const topText = document.querySelector('#topText');
const bottomText = document.querySelector('#bottomText');
const memeDiv = document.querySelector('#meme');
//listener for submit
document.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //if the user doesn't enter an image, or if they don't enter any text, don't generate the meme when they submit.
  if (imageLink.value === "") {
    return;
  } else if (topText === "" && bottomText === "") {
    return;
  }
  console.log(imageLink.value);

  //create elements

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  //set attribute for div containing our memes

  div.setAttribute("id", "meme");

  //When the page loads apply the users photo to the background of the grid
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    memeDiv.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLink.value})`; // < -- -- -
  });
  //create text and remove button for the memes
  const top = document.createElement("p"); //for top text
  const bottom = document.createElement("p"); //for bottom text
  const removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
  //remove button attributes
  removeBtn.setAttribute("id", "remove");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("type", "image");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("height", "200px");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("width", "200px");
  removeBtn.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/x-png-33.png"
  );
  //set attributes for text
  top.setAttribute("id", "top");
  top.innerText = topText.value;
  bottom.setAttribute("id", "bottom");
  bottom.innerText = bottomText.value;
  //put the top and bottom text with the remove button together with the same div
  div.appendChild(top);
  div.appendChild(bottom);
  div.appendChild(removeBtn);

  //append to the div
  document.querySelector("#memeContainer").appendChild(div);
  //reset
  imageLink.value = "";
  topText.value = "";
  bottomText.value = "";

})



document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === "remove") {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();

  } else {
    return;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#formContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
}

#memeContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 300px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#top,
#bottom,
#remove {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

#top {
  left: 225px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color:white; */
}

#bottom {
  top: 300px;
  left: 225px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color:white; */
}

#remove {
  top: -150px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 3;
  /* filter: opacity(1%); */
}

#remove:hover {
  z-index: 3;
  filter: opacity(25%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Meme Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>MEME GENERATOR</h1>
  <div id="formContainer">
    <form>
      <input id="imageLink" type="text" placeholder="please link to an image">
      <input id="topText" type="text" placeholder="TOP TEXT">
      <input id="bottomText" type="text" placeholder="BOTTOM TEXT">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="memeContainer"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is only called once whenever all HTML have been loaded. So you are only adding an event listener which never fires and thus nothing happens.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  memeDiv.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLink.value})`;
});
```

Remove the event listener and correct the `memeDiv` variable name to `div` and your code will run.

```
div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLink.value})`;
```

```js
const imageLink = document.querySelector('#imageLink');
const topText = document.querySelector('#topText');
const bottomText = document.querySelector('#bottomText');
const memeDiv = document.querySelector('#meme');
//listener for submit
document.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //if the user doesn't enter an image, or if they don't enter any text, don't generate the meme when they submit.
  if (imageLink.value === "") {
    return;
  } else if (topText.value === "" && bottomText.value === "") {
    return;
  }
  console.log(imageLink.value);

  //create elements

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  //set attribute for div containing our memes

  div.setAttribute("id", "meme");

  //When the page loads apply the users photo to the background of the grid
  div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLink.value})`; // < -- -- -
  //create text and remove button for the memes
  const top = document.createElement("p"); //for top text
  const bottom = document.createElement("p"); //for bottom text
  const removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
  //remove button attributes
  removeBtn.setAttribute("id", "remove");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("type", "image");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("height", "200px");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("width", "200px");
  removeBtn.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/x-png-33.png"
  );
  //set attributes for text
  top.setAttribute("id", "top");
  top.innerText = topText.value;
  bottom.setAttribute("id", "bottom");
  bottom.innerText = bottomText.value;
  //put the top and bottom text with the remove button together with the same div
  div.appendChild(top);
  div.appendChild(bottom);
  div.appendChild(removeBtn);

  //append to the div
  document.querySelector("#memeContainer").appendChild(div);
  //reset
  imageLink.value = "";
  topText.value = "";
  bottomText.value = "";

})



document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === "remove") {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();

  } else {
    return;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#formContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
}

#memeContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 300px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#top,
#bottom,
#remove {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

#top {
  left: 225px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color:white; */
}

#bottom {
  top: 300px;
  left: 225px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color:white; */
}

#remove {
  top: -150px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 3;
  /* filter: opacity(1%); */
}

#remove:hover {
  z-index: 3;
  filter: opacity(25%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Meme Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>MEME GENERATOR</h1>
  <div id="formContainer">
    <form>
      <input id="imageLink" type="text" placeholder="please link to an image">
      <input id="topText" type="text" placeholder="TOP TEXT">
      <input id="bottomText" type="text" placeholder="BOTTOM TEXT">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="memeContainer"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh I see! I misunderstood how that event worked. It runs fine now. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you out for future readers and fake internet points.

Comment: Haha. sorry about that very new to the website